# Merge multiple WorkBooks into one compiled WorkSheet

Tags: excel, merge, worksheet-function

I'm really beginning in VBA/Programming with just basic knowledge of Python.

**The struggle**

There are 6 different sheets in separate files that are manually merged every day. They all have the same configuration (`A:D` local numbers, `E:G` what I need to compile, `H` onwards miscelaneous information, with the first row as header).

I wish to create a macro that go to each file, select cells `E2:G(last row)` and paste it's text on this Master File without blank rows between them.

I have searched, tried and tweaked multiple codes found here, but none of them worked properly, so here I am, seeking help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Maybe you want to show us your first tries and code snippets you tried, so e can help you go further.

Comment: Thanks! I was so involved in searching that I forgot to look and see if there was any responses. Ended up achieving a functional code, managed even to shrink it into a loop (I had this sequence for each file, 6 in total). It was a matter of learning how to look for VBA expressions and writing something of my own, rather than trying to figure it out through complete codes.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it, lots of hours spent searching throught VBA's ways...

Here's the final code, 100% working:

```
Sub Teste_Array()

'Strings and paths definition
Dim Planilha() As Variant
Planilha = Array("03 - CONCRETO.xlsx", "04 - ALVENARIA.xlsx", "05 - METAIS.xlsx", "06 - MADEIRAS, PLÁSTICOS E COMPÓSITOS.xlsx", "07 - ABERTURAS.xlsx", "08 - ACABAMENTOS.xlsx")
Dim Caminho As String
Dim Abrir As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim LinhaFinal As Long

    Caminho = "C:\hd_servidor\8 BIBLIOTECA\3 REVIT\TEMPLATE\CATEGORIZAÇÃO\"

'Cancel animations for faster process
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
 
'Clear Contents of current compilation
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TESTE").Activate
        LinhaFinal = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A1:C" & LinhaFinal).ClearContents
 
'Loop, Copy and Paste to Compilation

    For i = 0 To 5
        Abrir = Caminho & Planilha(i)
        Workbooks.Open (Abrir)
    
        LinhaFinal = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("E2:G" & LinhaFinal).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TESTE").Activate
        LinhaFinal = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A" & LinhaFinal).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Workbooks(Planilha(i)).Close
        
    Next i

        
'Animations Back
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Edited to leave instructions in english, as I've written it in portuguese before.